# mongoimport displaying error: E11000 duplicate key error

Tags: python, json, mongodb, flask

I'm doing a tutorial on Flask. I'm trying to add some information from a json file into a MongoDB database

users.json

```
[{"id":1,"first_name":"Jacques","last_name":"Blazewicz","email":"jblazewicz0@posterous.com","password":"k9doaly"},
{"id":2,"first_name":"Budd","last_name":"Zellick","email":"bzellick1@uol.com.br","password":"kik8N0cyKG"},
{"id":3,"first_name":"Simone","last_name":"Brenston","email":"sbrenston2@squarespace.com","password":"9BO7nEvdci8"},
{"id":4,"first_name":"Waneta","last_name":"Stading","email":"wstading3@google.es","password":"GpzWY536X"},
{"id":5,"first_name":"Barbey","last_name":"Corder","email":"bcorder4@csmonitor.com","password":"BXFkbgEz"},
{"id":6,"first_name":"Becca","last_name":"Hartington","email":"bhartington5@wsj.com","password":"ijh3RfxcGB"},
{"id":7,"first_name":"Elyse","last_name":"Eddy","email":"eeddy6@archive.org","password":"QJHg5Gc0V"},
{"id":8,"first_name":"Reggie","last_name":"Souster","email":"rsouster7@4shared.com","password":"nmCeQGRC"},
{"id":9,"first_name":"Brnaby","last_name":"Abrahmson","email":"babrahmson8@digg.com","password":"BqOgwfIMJmTx"},
{"id":10,"first_name":"Yuma","last_name":"Graine","email":"ygraine9@tmall.com","password":"4VpkAWyL"},
{"id":11,"first_name":"Quinton","last_name":"Chater","email":"qchatera@squarespace.com","password":"7x6IYp"},
{"id":12,"first_name":"Raymund","last_name":"Moorman","email":"rmoormanb@indiatimes.com","password":"aRgaXm1"},
{"id":13,"first_name":"Boycey","last_name":"Ferrelli","email":"bferrellic@cnet.com","password":"VCKtIJEUi"},
{"id":14,"first_name":"Ty","last_name":"Raffeorty","email":"traffeortyd@cnet.com","password":"wVOd2oi"},
{"id":15,"first_name":"Judie","last_name":"Penella","email":"jpenellae@psu.edu","password":"0WP0F6516"},
{"id":16,"first_name":"Alden","last_name":"Gemlett","email":"agemlettf@independent.co.uk","password":"3rAW4wlTsCWz"},
{"id":17,"first_name":"Josephina","last_name":"MacLeod","email":"jmacleodg@livejournal.com","password":"gQ7ytj7CtA6"},
{"id":18,"first_name":"Lorene","last_name":"Lindeberg","email":"llindebergh@chron.com","password":"Q4WU8aHkm"},
{"id":19,"first_name":"Lamar","last_name":"Sotham","email":"lsothami@rediff.com","password":"5yyhnYPTDs"},
{"id":20,"first_name":"Derek","last_name":"Breakey","email":"dbreakeyj@home.pl","password":"jrz2kl2jeX"}]
```

I run this command in the terminal:

```
mongoimport --jsonArray --db UTA_Enrollment --collection user --file users.json
```

Instead of getting all 20 rows in the database, I only get the first row, and these error messages are displaying in the command line.

```
2021-02-25T17:47:40.654-0800    connected to: mongodb://localhost/
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }
2021-02-25T17:47:40.658-0800    1 document(s) imported successfully. 19 document(s) failed to import.
```

I had previously ran these lines of code in python and have since deleted the two entries, that are commented, from the database.

```
class User(db.Document):
    user_id     =   db.IntField( unique=True )
    first_name  =   db.StringField( max_length=50 )
    last_name   =   db.StringField( max_length=50 )
    email       =   db.StringField( max_length=30 )
    password    =   db.StringField( max_length=30 )

@app.route("/user")
def user():
    # User(user_id=1, first_name="Frank", last_name="Ho", email="frank.ho@uta.com", password="password123").save()
    # User(user_id=2, first_name="Mary", last_name="Jane", email="mary.jane@uta.com", password="abc1234").save()
    users = User.objects.all()
    return render_template("user.html", users=users)
```

I have no idea why this is happening, since the id is different for each entry. Thanks for the help

Comment: `E11000 duplicate key error collection: UTA_Enrollment.user index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: null }` - have you checked what kind of index is there on the `user_id` field? You can use `db.collection.getIndexes()` method in `mongo` shell to list all the indexes for a collection. Also, see [Unique Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/index.html).

Comment: @prasad_ When I enter db.user.getIndexes("user_id"), I get this back 
```uncaught exception: Error: listIndexes failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "no such command: '0'",
 "code" : 59,
 "codeName" : "CommandNotFound"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCollection.prototype.getIndexes@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:841:15
@(shell):1:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user_id` seems to have an index that forces the field values to be unique

But in your users.json file, there is no `user_id` field. So when importing the data it creates the field with a null value for all the users. And since the field, as to be unique you have this error `dup key:`

So to fix this, you have to remove the index on the user_id field.
The identifier of a document is named `_id` in mongodb

Comment: I’m completely new with this subject. 
Do I, enter db.collection.dropIndex(user) into the mongo db shell and then change the user_id variable to _id in the python code? How would I take the .json file given to me with the intended primary field as id, and use user_id as the variable name for mongodb’s interpretation of _id as the primary key.

Comment: you can remove the index with : `db.User.dropIndex("user_id")`. No need to add `_id` in your code, this field is declared implicitely. For the Json file, I think you will need to  rename "id" to "_id"

Comment: ```
{
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "ns not found test.User",
 "code" : 26,
 "codeName" : "NamespaceNotFound"
}
``` this shows up now when i enter the ```dropIndex()``` method into the shell. Also dropped the user_id field and enter the same ```mongoimport``` code above and still get the duplicate errors.

Comment: Never mind, if the collection is already created the error will arise. I fixed it by just typing in the ```mongoimport``` from scratch without the user collection already being created. Thanks for the help